# Setting up XMPPFramework for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I am working on an iOS app with a chat function. I want to know if there is any resource to configure the XMPPFramework in order to connect my iOS app with Openfire server.

I am new to XMPP Protocol.

I am currently learning about XMPP Stream and Rosters but I need to at least get the connection to work.

Please help.

Comment: Hi all After struggling a lot with xmpp, i got the connection work now, in order to do this i had to put the hostname of my mac, not the server name. but i can get connection an user authentication now. Thanks Keith for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get yourself started, dive into the sample iOS project in XMPPFramework-master > Xcode > iPhoneXMPP.

Preferably, begin tweaking in the project itself, and get your understanding from there before moving on to create your own XMPP project.

Basically to connect XMPP to OpenFire server, most of the configurations lie in AppDelegate.

1. Set your OpenFire server's details in the XMPP setup:

   ```
   - (void)setupStream
   {
       ...

       // Specify your server's IP address
       [xmppStream setHostName:@"123.12.123.12"];

       // Specify your host port
       [xmppStream setHostPort:5222];
   }
   ```
2. Assuming you have already created a contact in your OpenFire's roster, set a contact's credentials in the XMPP connection method:

   ```
   - (BOOL)connect
   {
       /**
        * Of course, do not hardcode in an actual implementation
        * Appending the server name at the back of user ID is necessary
        */
       myJID = @"user@openfire";
       myPassword = @"password goes here";
   }
   ```
3. Ensure you call the connect method in app launch method:

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
   {
       [self connect];
   }
   ```
4. Ensure you are connected here:

   ```
   - (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender
   {
       NSLog(@"User Connected");
       // You are connected to the server at this point.            
   }
   ```
5. Ensure you are authenticated here:

   ```
   - (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender
   {
       NSLog(@"User Authenticated");
       /**
        * Once you've reached this point,
        * Check your server for the online users. 
        * You should now be seen as "available".
        * Cheers!
        */
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you keith for your answer! in the hostname should i have to specify the ip address? or can i put the server name that i have, because in openfire server configuration appears to things that are making noise for me: first Server Name: openfire.example.net and hostName: Decuirs-Macbook-Pro.local, can i work directly with these or should i have to specify a direct ip address? Thanks for all

Comment: Hi Keith again, i checked the XMPPiOS that it's in the folder of XMPPFramework, but as i can see Robbie is not calling the [self connect] method to initiate the connectivity, he puts the [self setupStream] instead, why is that? Cheers.

Comment: @user3741129 Hello, yes you may specify your server name, however an IP address would be a better unique identifier. Regarding your second question, it's already called in the if-statement here: `if (![self connect])`

Comment: Hi Keith thanks again for your answer, now i can see activity in my openfire server, but i am now checking the presence, because as the user did connect and did authenticate it's getting offline presence, i have to methods -(void)goOnline and -(void)goOffline, but i guess my server only is getting offline presence! any advice? Thanks.

Comment: @user3741129 Check to see if you're online in `didReceivePresence` delegate method by `NSLog(@"%@", [presence fromStr]);`

Comment: Apparently nope! it did not print anything! just the normal stuff with socket and authentication but not the presence! any advice?

Comment: @user3741129 Is `[self goOnline];` called in `xmppStreamDidAuthenticate`?

Comment: Wow, you are a genius! that solved it!!! How did you become such an expert in xmpp?!!!!

Comment: I am working with a book called Mastering the xmpp framework, but the programmer assumes to much and just copy/paste code so that's why i am getting a hard time with XMPP, but thanks! i really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: @user3741129 You're certainly most welcome! :) Glad I could help! I'm working with XMPP too. It did not have a comprehensive documentation, so I aim to assist users with the solutions I know. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! *cries a little* i know that this could sound daring(my english is not quite good) but, is there anyway to chat with you so you can teach me a bit of xmpp? of course if you have the time and patience?! because i am new to this side of technology, it is the first time working with a server!

Comment: @user3741129 Well you could always post a new question in Stack Overflow so your answers would not just be limited to mine! I'll constantly keep a look out for new questions in the relevant tags too. Cheers. :)

Comment: Hi keith! sorry to bother you! for now the openfire server works fine! but there is a little problem, i just can test my application locally, meaning that my ios device is not connecting, i guess it have to be because of the hostname, how could i assign an ip address to work with it at the ios device? hope you can help!

Comment: @user3741129 Do create a new question, I'll answer you there. :)

Comment: OK keith sure i'll do!